# malloc memory allocation

Tags: c, malloc

I have a beginner question
I need to pass a pointer to a function and then allocate dinamic memory for this pointer.
I create the pointer in the main function, and then pass it to the specific function that's supposed to allocate the memory. but I get this error:
"hist_array may be used uninitialized in this function"

this are the rellavent lines from the program:
from the main:

```
    int* hist_array;
    fillHistogram(first_image,hist_array,max_value+1);
```

the function:

```
    void fillHistogram(int image[M][N], int* hist, int histLen){
    hist=(int*)malloc(sizeof(histLen)*(histLen));
```

I can't change the signature of the function, it was given to us as a structured file. so I would like to know what am I doing wrong.

and another question. the new array that I'm creating with malloc, I want all it's value in the begining to be 0. how do I do that in the shortest way?

Comment: Why would you allocate space to store a pointer? You have to store the result in a pointer anyway, so why not just store the function pointer there?

Comment: Regarding the other question, use `calloc`, `void *calloc(size_t nmemb, size_t size);`, that allocates space for `nmemb` objects each of size `size`, and zeros the allocated memory.

Comment: calloc is not allowed in this assignment

Comment: I didn't understand your first comment

Comment: Are you sure the second parameter of fillhistogram is `int *`?I think it should be `int**`,or you won't change the value of hist_array.

Comment: I didn't write the function signature, the teacher did. this is not something I can change.

Answer (score 2):

The intent appears to be that the calling code would do the allocation before calling `fillHistogram`.

The problem with your solution is that `hist` in `fillHistogram` is a copy of the pointer you passed in.  When you change the copy, the original is still uninitialized.

And you probably meant `sizeof(int)*histLen`.

Comment: my intention is to alocate memory for hist_array inside the fillhistogram function, and then use it for other things later after i fill it with the values it's supposed to get.

Comment: this whole combination of pointers+arrays+functions is still not very clear for me so I'm having a hard time with it.

Comment: @littlerunaway:  If you want to allocate the array in `fillHistogram` you'll need some way of returning it from `fillHistogram`, which requires changing the signature (which you say you can't do) to either return the new hist_array directly or take an extra `int **` argument which the hist_array gets written to.

Comment: can you give me an example of a second option?

Comment: so you basically saying I can't do it without changing the signature?

Answer (score 0):

First, I think you are missing parenthesis in you `sizeof`. Sizeof is a function, it needs its parameters. And doing `sizeof(histLen)*(histLen)` is telling malloc to 'reserve' sizeof(maxvalue+1), histlen times. I think that what you might want, since `hist_array` is a pointer to int, is to alloc a vector of integers. 
This is done with:

```
hist=malloc(histlen*sizeof(int)); /*I think it gets more easy to read with the lenght multiplier on the left*/
```

This tells malloc to 'reserve' memory for histlen integers.

another thing, since you're passing `hist_array` as argument and you don't return the malloc returning pointer for `hist_array`, you should probably say in your function that you want to modify it value in the main function. 
This is called passing an argument by reference, and to change its value inside the funcion you need to say that you want to change the pointed by value of the variable and not the copy of the variable. 
This would look like this:

```
*hist=malloc(histlen*sizeof(int)); /*The pointed by hist, which hist_array, is equal to malloc etc..*/
```

Hope this helps.